# Macro if, then... don't find the error

Tags: excel, vba

What is wrong with the Macro below? I just want to evaluate if one cell in one tab is greater than another cell in another tab. Then MsgBox:

```
Sub Comhouse()
  If Worksheets("(2.2) TRA worksheet").Range("AU425").Value > Worksheets("(2.0) Hotel Inventory").Range("S421").Value Then
    MsgBox ("Please check inventory imputed in Com and House for every day as it may be exiding the total inventory available")
    Exit Sub
  Else
    MsgBox ("All correct")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be ok, are the values in the cells correct? Are they valid numbers?

Comment: What error that throws you?

Comment: are you handling nulls correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check for numeric values:

```
Sub Comhouse()
   Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
   v1 = Worksheets("(2.2) TRA worksheet").Range("AU425").Value
   v2 = Worksheets("(2.0) Hotel Inventory").Range("S421").Value
   If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
      If v1 > v2 Then
         MsgBox ("Please check inventory imputed in Com and House for every day as it may be exiding the total inventory available")
         Exit Sub
      Else
         MsgBox ("All correct")
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox "non-numeric values"
   End If
End Sub
```